# Trouble with NSdate

Tags: objective-c

I am writing a program that has multiple views.  I want to pass a date variable between views.  I made a global variable using `extern NSDate *chooseDate`.  I declare the variable `NSDate *date` on one of the views. I then set `date = chooseDate`.  I then use the following code to add days to date;

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:(int)daycount];
date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
```

The problem seems to be that `chooseDate` is not being recognized as an `NSDate`.  The code crashes at `date = [calendar ...]`.  I am at a loss as to why this is happening.  I hope I have explained the clearly.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the code for your property(?) `date`?

Comment: date = chooseDate;
  
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[components setDay:(int)daycount];
date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
 
dateComponents = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
year = [dateComponents year];
month = [dateComponents month];
day = [dateComponents day];
hour = [dateComponents hour];
min = [dateComponents minute];
 
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[showDate setText:[formatter stringFromDate: date]];

Comment: Sorry about the format.  I can't remember how to make it look like the code in objective c.

Comment: I'm not seeing a definition for `calendar` anywhere. Where have you defined it, and are you giving it a value?

Comment: Yes, calendar is declared above this in the same method. Heres the code;
calendar= [[NSCalendar alloc]
      initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit |
NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit |
NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

Comment: Where are you creating/assigning/initializing the value of chooseDate? Please post the relevant sections of your code.

Comment: chooseDate is assigned from a date picker control with the following code;  chooseDate = [datePicker date];

Comment: Just before the line: date = chooseDate; Try logging the value of chooseDate (or "po chooseDate" in GDB) and see if it is what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it will work if you change `chooseDate = [datePicker date];` to `chooseDate = [[datePicker date] copy];`. If it does, the rest should be pretty much self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I've been away from this for a while.  Using "copy" as you stated fixed the problem, thanks a lot.  In all the different types of coding I have used in the past, setting one variable equal to another always resulted in an exact copy of the variable (i.e. choosedate = date, when both are defined as NSDate). Is this just an issue with copying dates, or should "copy" always be used when setting one variable equal to another?

Comment: The matter is, `[datePicker date]` returns an autorelease object, which means that when the method closure in which it was called ends the object is release. When you try to call it in `date = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];` the date pointer points to null or the memory address was allocated to a different object, thus the errors you get are not always a simple crash, sometimes you get some weird messages in the stack too.

As for `copy` what it does is to assure that even if the original object was release, you still have the copy and can use it.

Comment: Thanks, that explanation helps.  I was getting weird messages in the stack, and I didn't know what to make of them.

Comment: If it does, please consider choosing my answer, it helps others with similar issues and it helps me show off my reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `chooseDate` to an `autoreleased` instance. Are you sure it exists when you try to use it? You may need to `retain` it.

Comment: I checked.  It definitely exists when I set "date = chooseDate".  When I rem out the line of code "date = [calendar..]" the program runs fine.